Why are the Parent pages created at the moment when I to child route in flutter?
I am using navigator 2.0 with GoRouter.I found that in the widget tree When I go to a child route all the parent of that route are also created and their build method also triggered. Why is that?. Shouldn't those parent page be created when I actually go back.Similarly, when I push a new route without popping the old route the previous route is still there in the widget tree. Isn't this waste of memory to keep the state of the old page in memory when that page is not even visible?

In Flutter, the navigator works like the stack.

Last in First out

this means, which page is entered in last will come out first when you pop. so that when you push a new page into the stack the new page will be at the top of the old page and exist until you pop. so when you are poping the new page will be poped first and land on the old page as it is already there under the new page.

so that, if you don't need the old page then you can pop the old page
first after that push the new page. Then the old page no longer exists
under the new page as the old page popped first.

And, for saying about GoRouter,
it works like this, if you define a page as a child of another page, when you call that page you have to go through its parent. Because children always have to depend on their parents.

if your child's page can work without a parent and you have to call it
separately then you should declare it outside of that parent

